# Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade fails; error "package dependencies cannot be resolved"

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, libraries

I was trhing to upgrad my pc

**The basic PC info**

```
    description: Notebook
    product: Latitude 7490 (081C)
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    *-cpu
    description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz
    *generic:0
    product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsyste
    vendor: Intel Corporation
```

I have the following errors stopping the Ubuntu to update

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgl1:i386: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
             Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
             Depends: libglx0 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
```

I tried to do

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

But getting following errors

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Error!
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++ : Depends: g++-7 (>= 7.4.0-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 gcc-7 : Depends: libgcc-7-dev (= 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1:i386 : Depends: libglx0:i386 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolve
```

Any suggestions to fix the problem?

**Edit0**

Result of running 
`sudo apt-get install g++-7 libgcc-7-dev libglx0:i386 && sudo apt-get install g++ gcc-7 libgl1:i386`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++-7 is already the newest version (7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1).
libgcc-7-dev is already the newest version (7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1).
libglx0:i386 is already the newest version (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3).
gcc-7 is already the newest version (7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1).
libgl1:i386 is already the newest version (1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

**Edit 1**
Result of running command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
# deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

Comment: Please try `sudo apt-get install g++-7 libgcc-7-dev libglx0:i386 && sudo apt-get install g++ gcc-7 libgl1:i386` and then click [edit] and add the results to your questions.  Please do not click on Add Comment as new comments can shove old comments off screen; your information about your PC and installation should all go in the Question so we can all see your findings.

Comment: The Latitude 7490 has an x64 CPU.  Are you installing i386 packages for some reason in particular?

Comment: @tudor The i386 libraries are for a product I am working on, the target platform is under the x86 architecture. Will those libraries stop the Ubuntu upgrade?

Comment: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` please.

Comment: @nobody, thanks for your help, I put the results in Edit 1

Comment: I am able to update today without any changes. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Just a suggestion.

Go to Software and Updates

Select Other Software

Uncheck all PPAs

click close

click reload

Open Lite Welcome

Good luck!